# Is it possible to find out the exact computer an Mp3 was created on?

Tags: firefox-profile

If a Forensics professional examined an Mp3 file, would they be able to tell the mac address of the computer that created the file, or find any information that identified the computer that created the file?

Comment: Why, are you worried?

Answer (score 2):

No, when it comes down to it, any file can be opened with Notepad, and examined in UTF-8 format, the raw data in the file.

Contain in this is a `header`, and the actual raw data of the file.

The `header` would be the place if any that this information would exist, but, it does not. It  is a 32 byte chunk that contains basic information about what the file is, what the raw data is, and how it is compressed.

Sometime in the properties of the file, there will exist the Username, and possibly the Machine name, but nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. The only information that you can find on a media file is metadata, and its pretty easy to read. With photos, that information would involve what camera took it, gps data and so on. This usually isn't enough to pin it down to a *specific* camera. You might know a yoyodyne 2000 took the photo, but not which one.

Generally with audio files this is not as critical, and metadata is rarely useful in pinning it down. I've *never* come across any metadata beyond what tool was used to convert an audio file which identified the source, unless it was something the person who created it chose to add.

Considering mac addresses are used for networking, and networking has nothing to do with the audio chain, there's no reason that you'd have a mac address embedded in an audio file. There's no reason for something similar to exif data either - and thats how you'd identify a camera. In short, this is highly unlikely.

So, its unlikely unless it was a rather odd tool that was designed to store identifying data that created the file, that a forensic examiner can determine it was created by a specific computer.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases from the generated MP3 data you will be able to identify the encoder and something about the version of the encoder. Also in some cases you could be able to identify used system libraries and CPU architecture as they can possibly influence the generated data.

Some programs which create MP3s can also explicitly add their identification (program name, version) into the MP3 tags.

Those data can only supplement other data to narrow possible sources of an MP3 file. The data alone cannot be used to identify the source computer.